# How to check whether CKEditor has some HTML tags in it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I want to check the validation of CK texteditor whether it is empty or not

I apply this code:-

```
 if ($(".cleditorToolbar:eq(0)").next().next('iframe').contents().find('body').getInnerText().trim() == '') {
        $('span[id$=span_0]').html('Please enter question text');
        return false;
    }
```

When I enter some text in the Ck editor it works fine, but when i paste some image in it , it doesnt validate the HTML tags i.e.  tag , how to validate both html tags and text file  in Ck editor , Please help me out ??

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this for your "empty test" :

```
if(CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.getData() === '') {
    // It's empty
}
```

I think you can use 'dataProcessor' like this :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
   on: {
      pluginsLoaded: function(event) {
         event.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules({
            elements: {
               a: function(element) {
                  var attr = element.attributes;
                  if(attr.href && attr.href.indexOf('#') === -1) {
                     element.attributes.target = '_blank';
                  }
               },
               // remove script
               script: function(element) {
                  return false;
               }
            }
         });
      }
   }
});
```

[Documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-dataProcessor)